# How can I extract descriptive statistics from an entire table which contains factors?

Tags: r

Is there a way in R to extract multiple descriptive variables such as the mean, median and confidence intervals, into a separate dataframe?

This is the code I used to produce my dataframe:

```
health <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), Stroke = factor(c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1)), 
                     Diab = factor(c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1)), MI = factor(c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1)),
                     Age = factor(c(65,66,78,55,67,66,79,54,65,78)), 
                     Sex = factor(c("M","M","F","M","M","M","F","M","F","F")))
```

This is what the dataframe looks like:

```
   ID Stroke Age Sex MI_imp[, 1] diab_imp[, 1]
1   1      0  65   M           0             0
2   2      0  66   M           0             0
3   3      1  78   F           0             0
4   4      0  55   M           0             0
5   5      0  67   M           0             0
6   6      1  66   M           1             1
7   7      0  79   F           0             0
8   8      0  54   M           0             0
9   9      0  65   F           0             0
10 10      1  78   F           1             1
```

I a have tried running this code to extract the confidence intervals which returns the error:

```
sapply(health_imp[-1], quantile, probs=c(0.5, 0.05, 0.95), na.rm=TRUE)
```

```
Error in quantile.default(X[[i]], ...) : factors are not allowed
```

Comment: Please add the code you've tried.

Comment: `summary()` ???

Comment: Note that what you're requesting is applicable only to one variable in your sample data (Age) which is wrongly defined as a factor.

Answer (score 0):

the summary() function may be what you're looking for:

```
health<-data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), Stroke = factor(c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1)), Diab = factor(c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1)), MI = factor(c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1)), Age = factor(c(65,66,78,55,67,66,79,54,65,78)), Sex = factor(c("M","M","F","M","M","M","F","M","F","F")))
summary(health)
```

And to save into another data frame

```
health_table <- summary(health)
health_df <- as.data.frame(health_table)
```